# Load Hbase table from hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to load the hbase table from hive table, for that I am using the following approach and it works fine if I have only single column family in hbase table, however if I have multiple families it throws error.

**Approach**

source table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.employee_orc(id String, name String, Age int)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/tmp/employee_orc/table';
```

Create Hive table with Hbase Serde

```
CREATE TABLE temp.employee_hbase(id String, name String, age int)
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping' = ':key,emp:name,emp:Age')
    TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "bda:employee_hbase", "hfile.family.path"="/tmp/employee_hbase/emp", "hive.hbase.generatehfiles"="true");
```

export the hbase files

```
SET hive.hbase.generatehfiles=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp.employee_hbase SELECT DISTINCT id, name, Age FROM temp.employee_orc CLUSTER BY id;
```

Load the hbase table

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath`
hadoop jar /usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar completebulkload /tmp/employee_hbase/ 'bda:employee_hbase'
```

**Error**
I am getting following error if I have multiple column family in Hbase table,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators: java.io.IOException: Multiple family directories found in hdfs://hadoopdev/apps/hive/warehouse/temp.db/employee_hbase/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_1527799542731_1180_r_000000_0

**is there another way to load Hbase table if not this approach?**

Answer (score 0):

Bulk load from hive to hbase,  The target table can only have a single column family.

[bulk load of hbase](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseBulkLoad)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use hbase bulkload [hbase_bulkload](https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/managing-hbase/topics/hbase-using-bulkload.html) with support multiple column family
2. Or you can use multiple hive table for each  column family